# Introductory ARM - Assembly Error

Tags: for-loop, assembly, arm, keil, microprocessors

For a class just starting out with the ARM assembly language, we are required to implement a simple for-loop described below:

```
h=1;
for (i=0, i<5, i++)
    h=(h*3)-i;
```

I have written the following code in ARM assembly:

```
     AREA Prog2, CODE, READONLY
     ENTRY

     MOV r0, #1;         initialize h=1
     MOV r1, #0;         initialize i=0
loop CMP r1, #5;         at start of loop, compare i with 5
     MULLT r0, r0, #3;   if i<5, h=h*3
     SUBLT r0, r0, r1;   if i<5, h=h-i (ties in with previous line)
     ADDLT r1, r1, #1;   increment i if i is less than 5
     BLT loop ;          repeat loop of i is less than 5

stop B stop;             stop program
     END
```

The problem is that there is an error with the line

```
     MULLT r0, r0, #3;   if i<5, h=h*3
```

If I delete it from the code, everything works fine. I just cannot understand the issue with this one line. The error description given is "Bad register name symbol, expected integer register." I have tried loading #3 into a register then multiplying the two registers, but that didn't help. It simply changed the error message to "This register combination results in unpredictable behavior." I am new to this, so please offer only basic instructions as a fix for this. Thanks.

Comment: Read what your instruction set reference has to say about the `mul` instruction, particularly about what forms of operands it takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MUL` requires all operands to be registers, so you must use the form `MUL r0, rn, r0` where `rn` is some other suitable register.

If the result and the first operand are the same the result is unpredictable as the error says. This is due to the internal operation of the processor. This is why you must use `r0, rn, r0` and not `r0, r0, rn`

Comment: The quick reference card doesn't mention any limitation where `Rd` and `Rm` need to be the same, unless you are trying to use `muls` on Thumb-2 (where `muls` is otherwise not available). So, he could also get around the unpredictable behavior by using a third register, but I guess that would complicate the program needlessly.

Comment: @rjp Rd and Rm _don't_ need to be the same; I assume Sami is merely preserving the intent of the original code. The only restriction is that prior to ARMv6 the two input registers _can't_ be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by 3 is overrated anyway; ARM can do it with a single ridiculously idiomatic addition:

```
add r0, r0, r0 lsl #1    // r0 = r0 + r0 *2
```

Comment: If one counted from `0` down to `-4` instead of `0` to `4`, one could instead use an `mla r0, r0, r2, r1` with `r2 = 3`. I think I have that math right.